# Processing, controlp5 - Using saveFrame() to record controlp5 ControlWindow

Tags: processing

I'd like to use `saveFrame()` to record frames from a controlWindow created with controlp5. By default `saveFrame()` records only the main window of the sketch.
Is there a way to specify which window `saveFrame()` pulls from?

Are there any alternate ways to extract the buffer drawn to the controlWindow every frame?

Answer (score 0):

Windows in Java are typically [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). I haven't tested, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
//get to the java.awt.Component
Component window = yourP5ControlWindow.component();
//make a BufferedImage to store pixels into
BufferedImage snapshot = new BufferedImage(window.getWidth(),window.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//take a snapshot
window.paint( snapshot.getGraphics() );
//create a PImage out of the BufferedImage
PImage image = new PImage(snapshot);
//save,etc.
image.save("yourComponent.png");
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`PApplet.saveImage()` is essentially a wrapper around `PImage.save()`.
If you want to capture only a part of the screen, you should render it to a `PImage()` and then call `PImage.save()`.  `PImage.save()`, however, requires you to specify your own filename -- it will not auto-increment for you like `PApplet.saveImage()` does.

It doesn't appear simple to draw ControlP5 content into a separate buffer (PImage), but you can grab an arbitrary rectangle from the main graphics context and save that.

```
PImage screengrab = createImage(controlWindow.width, controlWindow.height, RGB);
screengrab.loadPixels();
loadPixels();
for (int i=0; i<screengrab.width*screengrab.height; i++) {
    // loop thru pixels and copy into screengrab.pixels...
    // i'll leave the math here as a fun exercise for you.
}
screengrab.updatePixels();
updatePixels();
screengrab.save("screengrab.png");
```